# I want to check only the network interfaces status on the server which is listed in the command output on linux bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, centos, rhel7

I want to get the output only the interface which is down based on the configured interfaces in the network-scripts directory.

```
for i in $(ls -1 /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-e*|sed 's/.*ifcfg-//g'); do grep -i 'down' /sys/class/net/$i/operstate; echo $i;done
```

How can I list only the interfaces which is down based on the input of the for iteration?

Thank you

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Can you post the input and sample output that you want besides the (broken) shell code?

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest with bash, its [Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and CentOS 7 / RHEL 7:

```
for i in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-e*; do 
  i=$(basename "$i")
  grep -qi 'down' "/sys/class/net/${i#*-}/operstate" && echo "${i#*-}"
done
```

`${i#*-}` removes from string `ifcfg-ens33` `ifcfg-` to get only interface name.

**Update**:

```
for i in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-e*; do
  grep -qi 'down' "/sys/class/net/${i##*-}/operstate" && echo "${i##*-}"
done
```

`${i##*-}` removes from string `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens33` `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-` to get only interface name.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this one does the job:

```
for i in $(ls -1 /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-e*|sed 's/.*ifcfg-//g'); do grep -i 'down' /sys/class/net/$i/operstate &> /dev/null;[ $? -eq "0" ] && echo $i;done|awk '{printf "%s ",$i} END {print ""}'
```